# How to write SQL queries to calculate aggregate server up-time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement in SQL where I have data of a server start stop time on daily basis for one month. I need the result where it should calculate the first start time of the day, last stop time of the day, total time server was started in a day on daily basis and for servers.

Table is like below and  expected output is also given.

Table:

```
Date & Time           Reader ServerID
3/14/2016 6:36:20 AM    ON  123
3/14/2016 6:58:45 AM    OFF 123
3/14/2016 8:06:19 AM    ON  123
3/14/2016 9:32:48 AM    OFF 123
3/15/16 6:00:00 AM      ON  123
3/15/16 6:01:00 AM      OFF 123
3/14/2016 9:46 AM       ON  124
3/14/2016 10:01 AM      OFF 124
3/14/16 11:01 AM        ON  124
3/14/16 12:01 PM        OFF 124
```

Expected output

```
UserID   FirstIN   Last Out  TotalInTime (min)    Date
123       6:00      09:32      86         3/14
123       06:00     06:01      1         3/15
124       9:46      12:01      75         3/14
```

Comment: Two different date formats, in the same column!?! Column data type?

Comment: Can you link your Table Data to your Expected Output? I see dates from 3/14 in your table sample, but your expected output is around 8/24

Comment: I have edited the table and expected output. Kindly check. @Arthur D

Comment: Hi @jarlh, I have edited it. Kindly check now and help.

Comment: I can't find the column data type. (You have both YY and YYYY years, which makes me guess it's a character data type?)

Answer (score 0):

So, for each day & server, you want the minimum and maximum time and the sum of minutes "ON".

First you need rows of ON/OFF pairs (pairs on a row, not pairs of rows) whose minutes you can calculate.  Then you sum the minutes and take the minimum and maximum times.

SQL Server has `datepart`.  You can use that to compute days.  To make On/Off pairs, join the table to itself along these lines:

```
select   A.ServerID, datepart(day, A.time) as day, 
         A.time as ON, min(B.time) as OFF
from     T as A join T as B on datepart(day, A.time) = datepart(day, B.time)
and      A.Reader = 'ON' and B.Reader = 'OFF'
and      A.time < B.time
group by A.ServerID, datepart(day, A.time), A.time
```

You can make a view like that, or a CTE, or insert the results in a temporary table.  Let's call the result `V`.

```
select   ServerID, day, min(ON), max(OFF)
       , sum(datediff(minute, OFF, ON)) as minutes
from     V
group by ServerID, day
```

(You can also nest the first query inside the second one.)

The trick is knowing how to find the "next" time for any pair (a question I've [answered often](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows)), and how to use the server's date functions.